# Does zeromq support IPC as a transport channel on windows?

Tags: python, windows, zeromq

I get the following error message, when I try the router example wiht python on Windows (Windows 8):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "router.py", line 43, in <module>
    client.bind("ipc://routing.ipc")
  File "socket.pyx", line 432, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.bind (zmq\core\socket.c:3870)
  File "checkrc.pxd", line 23, in zmq.core.checkrc._check_rc (zmq\core\socket.c:5712)
zmq.error.ZMQError: Protocol not supported
```

So I suppose that the IPC transport channel for zeromq is not suported on Windows (at least Windows 8). Is this true?

Comment: The problem is that Windows native IPC methods do not support event notification thus cannot integrate with a reactor.

Comment: @Steve-o: Windows named pipes support asynchronous I/O and trigger completion notifications to I/O completion ports (IOCP).  They integrate just fine with a proactor (or reactor) framework.  The ZeroMQ implementation for Windows probably uses the BSD(-ish) socket API and rather than using an IOCP, which would be a better explanation as to why ZeroMQ doesn't support the IPC transport on Windows.

Answer (score 18):

The question [How to use Zeromq's inproc and ipc transports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492377/how-to-use-zeromqs-inproc-and-ipc-transports) mentions that IPC relies on POSIX named pipes, which Windows doesn't support.

You should be able to use TCP on a Loopback Interface instead without trouble.

Comment: Indeed - the question becomes, why would you ever use IPC instead of TCP for anything?  According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10875272/178757), TCP between localhost processes is just as fast as IPC anyway!

Answer (score 15):

It is not supported on Windows, but TCP over localhost gives much the same performance as IPC, on Linux and OS/X and I'd just use that on Windows too.

Answer (score 8):

With Win 10 now supporting AF_UNIX libzmq was updated to support IPC. It was added to the 4.3.3 release. For more information see this [pull](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/3691)